# With MSChart, how to do round the edges of the bar graph?

Tags: graph, mschart

I am using System.Drawing to create the following image, but I want to switch over to MSChart (`System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting`).

Has anyone been able to create the rounded edges that you see in my bar? Both bars (blue & gray) have rounded smooth edges.

[image: Simple rounded edged graph created by drawing the bar chart manually]

**UPDATE: (Adding a method returning my Chart that needs curves)**

```
    private MSChart.Chart createChart3(double dataPointYvalue, string chartName, MSChart.Axis yAxis, SysDraw.Size sizeChart)
{
    // Chart
    // --------------------------------
    MSChart.Chart chart6 = new MSChart.Chart();
    chart6.BorderlineWidth = 0;
    chart6.BorderSkin.BackColor = SysDraw.Color.Empty;
    //chart6.Name = chartName;
    //chart6.Size = new SysDraw.Size(720, 90);
    chart6.Width = 720;
    chart6.Height = 90;
    chart6.AntiAliasing = MSChart.AntiAliasingStyles.All;
    chart6.TextAntiAliasingQuality=MSChart.TextAntiAliasingQuality.High;
    chart6.IsSoftShadows = false;

    // ChartAreas collection
    // --------------------------------
    string chartAreaName = "Default";
    SysDraw.Font labelFont = new SysDraw.Font("Arial Narrow", 10,SysDraw.FontStyle.Regular);
    SysDraw.Font labelFontBold = new SysDraw.Font("Arial Narrow", 10,SysDraw.FontStyle.Bold);



    #region Chart Area
    MSChart.ChartArea chartArea6 = new MSChart.ChartArea();
    chartArea6.Area3DStyle.Enable3D = false;

    chartArea6.BackGradientStyle = MSChart.GradientStyle.TopBottom;
    chartArea6.BackColor = grayStart;
    chartArea6.BackSecondaryColor = grayEnd;
    chartArea6.BorderDashStyle=MSChart.ChartDashStyle.NotSet;
    chartArea6.Name = chartAreaName;

    // --   Axes under Area collection
    // --------------------------------
    chartArea6.AxisX.Enabled = MSChart.AxisEnabled.False;
    chartArea6.AxisX.IsMarginVisible = false;
    //chartArea6.AxisX.LabelStyle.Font = new SysDraw.Font("Trebuchet MS", 8.25F, SysDraw.FontStyle.Bold);
    chartArea6.AxisX.LabelStyle.Font = labelFont;
    chartArea6.AxisX.LabelStyle.Interval = 1D;
    chartArea6.AxisX.LineColor = SysDraw.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))));
    chartArea6.AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = SysDraw.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))));




    chartArea6.AxisY.CustomLabels.Add(createLabelRegion(1,"Underweight",0D,18.49D,SysDraw.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(128)))), ((int)(((byte)(128)))))));
    chartArea6.AxisY.CustomLabels.Add(createLabelRegion(1,"Normal",18.5D,24.9D,SysDraw.Color.Black));
    chartArea6.AxisY.CustomLabels.Add(createLabelRegion(1,"Overweight",25D,29.9D,SysDraw.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(128)))), ((int)(((byte)(128)))))));
    chartArea6.AxisY.CustomLabels.Add(createLabelRegion(1,"Obese",30D,50D,SysDraw.Color.Red));
    chartArea6.AxisY.CustomLabels.Add(createLabelRegion(0,"18.5",15.5D,21.5D,SysDraw.Color.Black));
    chartArea6.AxisY.CustomLabels.Add(createLabelRegion(0,"25",23D,27D,SysDraw.Color.Black));
    chartArea6.AxisY.CustomLabels.Add(createLabelRegion(0,"30",28D,32D,SysDraw.Color.Black));

    chartArea6.AxisY.Enabled = MSChart.AxisEnabled.True;
    chartArea6.AxisY.Interval = 50D;
    chartArea6.AxisY.Maximum = 50D;
    chartArea6.AxisY.Minimum = 0D;
    chartArea6.AxisY.IntervalType = MSChart.DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
    //chartArea6.AxisY.LabelStyle.Font = new SysDraw.Font("Trebuchet MS", 8.25F, SysDraw.FontStyle.Bold);

    chartArea6.AxisY.LabelStyle.Font = labelFontBold;

    chartArea6.AxisY.LineColor = SysDraw.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))));
    chartArea6.AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = SysDraw.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))));
    chartArea6.AxisY.MajorTickMark.Enabled = false;

    chartArea6.AxisY2.Enabled = MSChart.AxisEnabled.True;
    chartArea6.AxisY2.Interval = 50D;
    chartArea6.AxisY2.Maximum = 50D;
    chartArea6.AxisY2.Minimum = 0D;
    chartArea6.AxisY2.MajorTickMark.Enabled = false;
    #endregion
    chart6.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea6);

    // Series Collection Editor
    // --------------------------------
    #region Series
    // --   Datapoints
    // --------------------------------
    MSChart.DataPoint dataPoint19 = new MSChart.DataPoint(0D,dataPointYvalue);

    MSChart.Series series7 = new MSChart.Series();
    series7.BackGradientStyle = MSChart.GradientStyle.TopBottom;
    series7.Color = blueStart;
    series7.BackSecondaryColor = blueEnd;
    series7.BorderColor = SysDraw.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(180)))), ((int)(((byte)(26)))), ((int)(((byte)(59)))), ((int)(((byte)(105)))));
    series7.ChartArea = chartAreaName;
    series7.ChartType = MSChart.SeriesChartType.Bar;
    series7.Name = "PlotMemberValue";
    series7.Points.Add(dataPoint19);
    #endregion
    chart6.Series.Add(series7);

    // Legend
    // --------------------------------
    #region Legend
    MSChart.Legend legend6 = new MSChart.Legend();
    legend6.BackColor = SysDraw.Color.Transparent;
    legend6.Enabled = false;
    legend6.Font = new SysDraw.Font("Trebuchet MS", 8.25F, SysDraw.FontStyle.Bold);
    legend6.IsTextAutoFit = false;
    legend6.Name = "Default";
    #endregion
    //chart6.Legends.Add(legend6);

    // Title
    // --------------------------------

    // Annotations
    // --------------------------------
    chart6.Annotations.Add(valueAnnotation(dataPoint19));
    chart6.Annotations.Add(regionDividerLine(dataPoint19,chartAreaName,18.5D));
    chart6.Annotations.Add(regionDividerLine(dataPoint19,chartAreaName,25D));
    chart6.Annotations.Add(regionDividerLine(dataPoint19,chartAreaName,30D));

    return chart6;
}
```

Comment: Hi what exactly have you done to make the edges rounded

Comment: We have moved away from MSChart. We use a pure CSS approach now.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the basic chart you are using and i can continue to get it closer however I believe you will be using

```
    chart.BorderSkin.SkinStyle = BorderSkinStyle.Emboss;
```

Comment: Close, but the BorderSkin is the outer border for the entire chart. I'm focusing on plot area & series.

Comment: I added the code, as requested. This is basically, what I'm dealing with. I need the hard edges to be rounded.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of to do something like that would be to use the **PostPaint** event in order to draw on top of the standard square bars. You could try to hide the corner by drawing a transparent bitmap for example. It might be quite tricky to achieve pixel perfect alignment though. The code below demonstrate the principle only and does not resolve how to correctly position the bitmap.

```
private void chart1_PostPaint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartPaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // Painting series object
        if (e.ChartElement is System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series)
        {
            Series series = (Series)e.ChartElement;

            foreach (DataPoint pt in series.Points)
            {
                // Load bitmap from resource
                System.Drawing.Image bitmap = Properties.Resources.corners;

                // Set Red color as transparent
                ImageAttributes attrib = new ImageAttributes();
                attrib.SetColorKey(Color.Red, Color.Red, ColorAdjustType.Default);

                // Calculates marker position depending on the data point X and Y values
                RectangleF imagePosition = RectangleF.Empty;
                imagePosition.Y = (float)e.ChartGraphics.GetPositionFromAxis(
                    "Default", AxisName.X, pt.XValue);
                imagePosition.X = (float)e.ChartGraphics.GetPositionFromAxis(
                    "Default", AxisName.Y, pt.YValues[0]);

                imagePosition = e.ChartGraphics.GetAbsoluteRectangle(imagePosition);
                imagePosition.Width = bitmap.Width;
                imagePosition.Height = bitmap.Height;
                imagePosition.X -= bitmap.Width - 1;
                imagePosition.Y -= 1;

                // Draw image
                e.ChartGraphics.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap,
                    Rectangle.Round(imagePosition),
                    0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height,
                    GraphicsUnit.Pixel,
                    attrib);

                // Dispose image object
                bitmap.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Very clever approach. I need to clarify that I am not rendering the chart to any UI for interaction. It is rendered as a chart and then I use SaveImage() to a memory stream where the image is added to a PDF with iTextSharp. Painting events are not an option.

Comment: Without paint events, I am struggling for ideas. One would be to use stacked bars and always add a fixed value for the second value. Set this to a distinctive solid colour. Once you have generated the bitmap you can post-process it and replace those fixed coloured rectangle at the end of each of your desired bar with the rounded end you need. By all mean that is a very far fetched solution.